# Scala pattern matching throws match error when returned null in tuple

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

Below are two snippets , i am unable to understand why one executes successfully and the other throws the run time exception.

Snippet1 :

```
val str = "HELP"

val perfectTuple: (String, String) = str match {
    case "NO-HELP" => ("First Help", "Second Help")
    case "OTHER-HELP" => ("I won't Help!", "Even,I won't Help!")
    case "HELP" => (null,"Single Help")
    case _ => throw new NoSuchMethodException

  }
```

Snippet2:

```
val str = "HELP"

val (firstPart:String, secondPart:String) = str match {
  case "NO-HELP" => ("First Help", "Second Help")
  case "OTHER-HELP" => ("I won't Help!", "Even,I won't Help!")
  case "HELP" => (null,"Single Help")
  case _ => throw new NoSuchMethodException
}
```

==========================

There is a very little difference between the two snippets. One stores the returned tuple into a value 'perfectTuple' of type tuple2 and this one gets executed successfully.

Other one extract the values out of the tuple 2 and stores them into the string values and throws a run time 'scala.matchError'.

Is this a bug in scala?

I have tried this on scala 2.10.5 and 2.11.7

Thanks in advance.

=============

one more scenario, in which i can assign null to a string from pattern matching and this one works absolutely perfect:
Snippet3:

```
val str = "HELP"

val assignNullToString: String = str match {

    case "NO-HELP" => "ONE"
    case "OTHER-HELP" => "TWO"
    case "HELP" => null
    case _ => throw new NoSuchMethodException
}
```

So i assume, its not that i am assigning null to a String is causing a problem, its something to do with Tuple ? and what is the problem with Snippet 2 , whereas Snippet 1 is running absolutely fine.

Answer (score 5):

Well the second example uses the `unapply` of `case class Tuple2`.

Now, I have not looked at the optimized code of `Tuple2.unapply` but I'd guess that at some point it does a type match on values of the tuple.

And one simply cannot type match on `null`.

```
val str: Any = null

str match {
  case _: String => "yay"
  case other => "damn"
}
|-> res1: String = damn
```

**Update**

Let's disect your second example a bit:

```
val str = "HELP"

val (firstPart:String, secondPart:String) = str match {
  case "NO-HELP" => ("First Help", "Second Help")
  case "OTHER-HELP" => ("I won't Help!", "Even,I won't Help!")
  case "HELP" => (null,"Single Help")
  case _ => throw new NoSuchMethodException
}
```

When we extract the match, we get:

```
val tuple: (String, String) = str match {
  case "NO-HELP" => ("First Help", "Second Help")
  case "OTHER-HELP" => ("I won't Help!", "Even,I won't Help!")
  case "HELP" => (null,"Single Help")
  case _ => throw new NoSuchMethodException
}
```

Now, you put it into the `unapply` function of `Tuple2`. Have a look at the signature:

```
def unapply[A, B](tuple: Tuple2[_, _]): Option[(A, B)]
```

So the types on the values of the incoming tuple are *erased*!
However, when you say

```
val (first: String, second: String) = tuple
```

You are calling `Tuple2.unapply` with type parameters `[String, String]`, explicitly requiring the result to be `(String, String)`.

To be able to return `Option[(String, String)]`, the unapply function will have to type match both values.

One could imagine the `Tuple2` companion object to look something like, but in truth far more efficient and sophisticated:

```
object Tuple2 {
  def apply[A, B](_1: A, _2: B): Tuple2[A, B] = new Tuple2(_1, _2)

def unapply[A, B](tuple: Tuple2[_, _]): Option[(A, B)] = {
  val a: Option[A] = tuple._1 match { case a: A => Some(a) }
  val b: Option[B] = tuple._2 match { case b: B => Some(b) }

  a.zip(b).headOption
}
```

Now here is the line that would throw a MatchError:

```
  val a: Option[A] = tuple._1 match { case a: A => Some(a) }
```

As I said earlier, I have not looked at the optimized code of `Tuple2`, but I'm reasonably confident that this is pretty close to what actually happens.

You could of course always relax your requirements a bit:

```
val str = "HELP"

val (firstPart, secondPart) = str match {
  case "NO-HELP" => ("First Help", "Second Help")
  case "OTHER-HELP" => ("I won't Help!", "Even,I won't Help!")
  case "HELP" => (null,"Single Help")
  case _ => throw new NoSuchMethodException
}
```

Should work well enough for most cases but would probably only postpone the pain.

**EDIT 2**

I'd recommend to always be aware of the fact that when using an extractor to bind vals, one is using syntactic sugar for a pattern match, as the pattern match may always fail with a match error.

Here are some obvious examples that I saw happen in less obvious ways a couple of times.

```
val foo = ("lorem", 2)
val (lorem: String, bad: String) = foo // fail 

case class Bar(name: String, age: Option[Int])
val bar = Bar("Sam", None)
val Bar(name, Some(age)) = bar // fail
```

Comment: the Tuple 2 case class definition below declares Covariant T1 and T2 ...:
case class Tuple2[+T1, +T2](_1: T1, _2: T2) extends Product2[T1, T2] with Product with Serializable

Which means that it should accept a null object under the type of String and should be okay?

Comment: @Tarun you can pass `null` as whatever you want. But an extractor does not simply use `asInstanceOf` to return the requested value type. That is not exactly type safe. Instead, (usually) a type match is used to check if the type matches. I'll extend my answer a bit. ...

Comment: Your explanation kind of illustrate why null is causing the scala to throw a match error... Thanks for that :)

However, if i can take the liberty to probably extend my question a little further "Won't that be best that scala allows the developer to expect the same result  for both Snippet 1 and Snippet 2 , as R.H.S of both snippets are same and their L.H.S. are more or less syntactic sugar for extracting the value obtained from R.H.S?"

Comment: @Tarun I wouldn't call the usage in Snippet 2 'more or less syntactic sugar for extracting the value obtained from R.H.S'. See EDIT 2 of my answer

Answer (score 0):

The third pattern `"Help"` is matched but the error is because you are trying to assign `null` to `firstPart` which expects a `String`. You can see a similar error in the smaller example below. You code behaves similarly.

```
scala> val (firstPart: String, secondPart: String) = ("foo", "bar")
firstPart: String = foo
secondPart: String = bar

scala> val (firstPart: String, secondPart: String) = (null, "bar")
<console>:10: error: pattern type is incompatible with expected type;
 found   : String
 required: Null
       val (firstPart: String, secondPart: String) = (null, "bar")
```

If you change `null` in the first part of the tuple to a `String` it works fine.

Comment: This doesn't really explain what's going on in this particular case - `val foo: String = null` is fine.

Comment: Try `val (a: String, b: String) = (null.asInstanceOf[String], "b")`

Comment: Thanks Brian for the response. I have included one more scenario which assigns null to string from pattern matching. so i am sure assigning null is not the real issue here.

Comment: @m-z I get a `scala.MatchError` with that. Would `val (a: Option[String], b: Option[String]) = (None, Some("b"))` be preferable?

Comment: @Tarun Assigning null to an element of a tuple and a value behave differently as you have discovered. These are different cases.

Comment: @Tarun see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/2025068/390708 and this one http://stackoverflow.com/q/7819527/390708.